# Svelte components store - load state into - from URL hash parameters

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

If we have a **S**ingle **P**age **A**pplication built with **Svelte** with a bunch of components and a store where we keep our current app state, is there an recommended way to store the store state changes into the **# hash part of the current URL** and be able to re-load the same state from the full URL?

It can be done manually by parsing the current URL with `location.search()`.

Storing of parameters can be done with `location.search("key", "value")`.

Some questions:

- When to load the state from URL? What would be the App init entry
  point?
- When to store the state from the store to the URL? Is there a generic
  way to do this?

Comment: never used it but looks like [`svelte-spa-router`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-spa-router#querystring-parameters) provides querystring support out of the box.

Comment: @skyboyer thanks, have not seen it. This is all new to me so when you are learning you tend to re-implement the wheel.

Comment: could you append your answer? other people how will land here by searching will not check comments for sure :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:**

[svelte-spa-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-spa-router#querystring-parameters) seems to offer querystring support out of the box.

---

I ended up using [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) and [polyfill](https://github.com/jerrybendy/url-search-params-polyfill) for it to write functions which serialize and deserialize config object which is kept in store:

```
import 'url-search-params-polyfill';

export function deserializeConfig(serializedConfig, resultConfig) {
  let hashParams = new URLSearchParams(serializedConfig);
  for (const hashParameterAndValue of hashParams.entries()) {
    const key = hashParameterAndValue[0];
    const value = hashParameterAndValue[1];

    const decodedKey = decodeUrlParameterKey(key);
    const decodedValue = decodeUrlParameterValue(value);

    resultConfig[decodedKey] = decodedValue;
  }


export function serializeConfig(config) {
  const hashParams = new URLSearchParams("");

  for (const key in config) {
    const value = config[key];
    const encodedValue = encodeParameterValue(value);
    const encodedKey = encodeParameterKey(key);;
    hashParams.set(encodedKey, encodedValue);
  }

  const serializedConfig = hashParams.toString();
  return serializedConfig;
}
```

To use it with to serialize / deserialize state from the URL hash:

in main.js:

```
import { configFromStore } from "./stores.js";

let config = {};

// when config from store changes
configFromStore.subscribe(updatedConfig => {
    config = updatedConfig;

   // check if the config was really modified and does not match the default
   if (!isEquivalent(updatedConfig, defaultConfig)) {
     // update URL hash after store value has been changed
     const serializedConfig = serializeConfig(updatedConfig);
     window.location.hash = "#" + serializedConfig;
   }
}

// on main app start, parse state from URL hash
const hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash && hash.length > 1) {
    const serializedConfig = hash.substr(1);
    deserializeConfig(serializedConfig, config);
    configFromStore.set(config);
}
```

It is a bit more trickier than this since you need to take care about the default config and remove values from the serialized config that are same with the default.
Also the subscribe is called initially when the config is loaded even though the config is not yet modified at this point.